# scraping and returning it as json in express

Tags: javascript, json, cheerio

i'm scraping data from a website and then i want to show it as json in the browser, however even though when i `console.log()` recipes array it show the data, but it does not send anything to the browser how come it does not show the json array in browser?

```
router.get('/scrape', function(req, res, next) {

  res.json(scrapeUrl("http://url"));

})

function scrapeUrl(url) {
  request(url, function(error, response, html){

    // First we'll check to make sure no errors occurred when making the request
    if(!error){

      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      var recipes = [];



      $('div.article-block a.picture').each(function(i, elem) {

        var deepUrl = $(this).attr('href');

        if(!$(this).attr('href').indexOf("tema") > -1) {
          request(deepUrl, function(error, response, html){

            // First we'll check to make sure no errors occurred when making the request
            if(!error){


              var $ = cheerio.load(html);

              var image = $('div.article div.article-main-pic img').attr('src');
              var title = $('div.recipe h2.fn').text();

              var object = {url: deepUrl, title : title, image : image};

              recipes.push(object);

            }

          });

        }

      });
      return recipes;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ScrapeURl is asynchronous function.

So to fix it do like this

`router.get('/scrape', function(req, res, next) {
  scrapeUrl("http://url", function(err, resp){
     res.json(resp);
  });
});`

And add callback in scrapeUrl

```
scrapeUrl (url, cb) {
  request(url, function(error, response, html){
    //rest of your code
    //Make sure callback are called after last request return results.
    cb(err, resp)
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is only returning the array, not placing that array in the DOM.

If you just want to show the array of data in the browser, you could create a container that you'll place the content into:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

And then replace your return value with this:

```
$('#content').text(JSON.stringify(recipes));
```